# Trying to get namespace behavior in TypeScript to work in RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I'm trying to use TypeScript to create a common library for a set of related web sites.  I started off code like this:

```js
module Lib {
    export module Tools {
        export class Opener {
            public Path: string;
            public static Open(): boolean { /* ... */ }
        }
        export class Closer { /* ... */ }
    }

    export module Controls {
        export class InfoDisplay { /* ... */ }
        export class Logon { /* ... */ }
    }

    export module Entities {
        export class BigThing { /* ... */ }
        export class LittleThing { /* ... */ }
    }
}

var Initial: boolean = Lib.Tools.Opener.Open();
var CustomOpener: Lib.Tools.Opener = new Lib.Tools.Opener();
```

This worked quite well and allowed me to use some of TypeScript's nice features, like static methods and namespaced class names.  As the project has grown, however, the need to use a module system for dependency resolution has become clear.  My problem is that I'm a RequireJS noob so I can't quite figure out how get preserve the desirable features mentioned above to work in my project once RequireJS is in the mix.  Here's my best attempt so far (which, to save space, only shows the code trail for Opener):

```js
// ---- Opener.ts --------------------------------------------------------
/// <reference path="../typings/requirejs/require.d.ts"/>

class Opener {
    public Path: string;
    public static Open(): boolean { /* ... */ }
}

export = Opener;
```

---

```js
// ---- Tools.ts --------------------------------------------------------
/// <reference path="../typings/requirejs/require.d.ts"/>

import Opener = require("./Opener");
import Closer = require("./Closer");

class Tools {
    public Opener: Opener = new Opener();
    public Closer: Closer = new Closer();
}

export = Tools;
```

---

```js
// ---- ReqLib.ts --------------------------------------------------------
/// <reference path="../typings/requirejs/require.d.ts"/>

import Tools = require("./Tools");

class ReqLib {
    public Tools: Tools = new Tools();
}

export = ReqLib;
```

---

```js
// ---- App.ts --------------------------------------------------------
import ReqLib = require("./ReqLib");
var RL: ReqLib = new ReqLib();

var Initial: boolean = RL.Tools.Opener.Open();                       // <== red squiggles
var CustomerOpener: ReqLib.Tools.Opener = new ReqLib.Tools.Opener(); // <== red squiggles
```

Visual Studio doesn't like the last two lines.  It can't see the static method in the first line and it just flat out doesn't like the second because it looks like instances are being used as types.  It's also the more troubling case because TypeScript kind of needs to have types to work with.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `RL.Tools.Opener` is resolving to `new Opener();` The static `public static Open()` does not exist on an *instance* but instead exists on the `class Opener`, hence the compiler error.

Suggestion : don't make it static. There might be other suggestions but now you know the reason for the error.

## UPDATE

for `new ReqLib.Tools.Opener();` you need to do `new ReqLib().Tools.Opener;`

Comment: Right.  Thanks for the confirmation of what I'd been suspecting.  I think that makes the first issue pretty closely related to the first then, because accessing the static methods would seem to depend on having the type definitions survive through multiple layers of RequireJS.  Converting the static methods to instance methods is a plausible workaround, but I still have no idea how to deal with the second issue, and that's a total show stopper for my current architecture.

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen that type of construction before.  It would have taken me a long time to come up with that.  Thanks!

Still though, it only solves the right half of the second problem, not the left half.  How do I specify that something has to be of type ReqLib.Tools.Opener, like the variable in my example or, more importantly, in a context that can't be inferred by the compiler, like a parameter in a new function?